# ls: terminated by signal 13 when using xargs

Tags: find, xargs

I'm using the following command to delete four largest size files in a folder:

```
find "/var/www/site1/" -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs ls -1S | head -n 4 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

It works fine, but from time to time throws broken pipe error:

```
xargs: ls: terminated by signal 13
```

Comment: You can add: -print | uniq | xargs ls -1S......

Comment: Have a look at this answer for a reasonably clean way to solve the problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558018/264963    basically put an -exec read \; in the find command and give it as many imput lines as you want it to handle.

Answer (score 51):

I ran across a similar issue and found this thread on search for an answer:

Signal 13 means something is written to a pipe where nothing is read from anymore (e.g. see http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm ).

The point here is that the ls command as executed by xargs is still writing output when the following head command already got all the input it wants and closed its input-pipe. Thus it's safe to ignore, yet it's ugly. See also the accepted answer in https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error

Answer (score 17):

You are purposely terminating your program with `head -n 4`, which creates the broken pipe because you terminated it before the "caller" finished. Since this is expected by you, you can ignore the error by redirecting it to `/dev/null` which discards it:

`find "/var/www/site1/" -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs ls -1S | head -n 4 
| xargs -d '\n' rm -f 2>/dev/null`

Comment: I'd rather redirect the "offending xargs":
`<cmd> | xargs ls -1S 2>/dev/null | head | <cmd>`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, "terminated by signal 13", under different circumstances and other answers here helped me work out the fix. I'd like to expand on the nature of the problem:

```bash
corpy386 ~/gw/Release/5.1_v9/ClaimCenter $ find . -name '*.pcf' -not -name '*build*' | xargs grep -l ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet | ( read f && echo $f && grep 'def=' $f )
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.auto.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
xargs: grep: terminated by signal 13
```

So here's the same error and I'd only get a single line of output when I knew there are numerous files that match what I'm looking for. The problem was that `xargs` is producing multiple lines of output and `read` is only consuming a single line before ending. `xargs` tries to write the rest of its results to one of the pipes but the receiving end has already quit and gone home. Hence, signal 13: Broken Pipe.

The fix was to consume all of `xargs`'s output by looping - change  `read f && do_some_things` (which reads one time only) to `while read f; do do_some_things; done`.

```bash
corpy386 ~/gw/Release/5.1_v9/ClaimCenter $ **find . -name '*.pcf' -not -name '*build*' | xargs grep -l ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet | while read f; do echo $f; grep 'def=' $f; done**
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.auto.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.gl.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.Pr.pcf
      def="ClaimSnapshotGeneralPRPanelSet(Claim, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.Trav.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.wc.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/build/idea/classes/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotLossDetailsScreen.default.pcf
      def="ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet(Claim, SnapshotParam)"
./modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.auto.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.gl.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.Pr.pcf
      def="ClaimSnapshotGeneralPRPanelSet(Claim, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.Trav.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet.wc.pcf
          def="AddressSnapshotInputSet(Snapshot.LossLocation, Snapshot)"
./modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/claim/snapshot/default/ClaimSnapshotLossDetailsScreen.default.pcf
      def="ClaimSnapshotGeneralPanelSet(Claim, SnapshotParam)"
```

This isn't exactly the same situation as OP's script - They wanted a part of the input and cut it off on purpose, I wanted the whole stream and cut it off by accident - but the shell semantics work out the same. Programs tend to be written to keep running *until they have consumed all their input* rather than test to see if their recipient is still listening.

Comment: Yes I know I got the options to `find` wrong - should have used 'path' instead of 'name' to filter out directories. I've left the commands as-is for the sake of illustration, since fixing the predicate made only one file come back in the first version, which meant the broken-pipe situation didn't even occur.

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid this is to switch `head` for `perl -ne`.

Starting with your original command:

```bash
find "/var/www/site1/" -maxdepth 1 -type f |
  xargs ls -1S |
  head -n 4 |
  xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

As you've probably learned from the other answers, the `head -n 4` process exits after accepting 4 lines from `ls -1S`. This confuses `ls -1S`.

Replace `head -n 4` with `perl -ne 'print if $i++ <= 4'`. The perl process will stay alive and accept every line from `ls -1S`, so no more error. But it will only pass along lines 1 - 4.

Here's the new command:

```bash
find "/var/www/site1/" -maxdepth 1 -type f | 
  xargs ls -1S |
  perl -ne 'print if $i++ <= 4' |
  xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-n

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to find and destroy "xargs" when "head" job is done

```
$ cat  /tmp/50m.txt  | xargs   -n1  echo   | { head -n2; kill -2 $(pidof xargs); }; echo "${PIPESTATUS[*]}"
141 130 0
```

130 return code shows that "xargs" got signal 2 (SIGINT) and was killed by its signal handler silently.

141 return code shows that "cat" got signal 13 (SIGPIPE) and was killed by its signal handler silently in comparison with "xargs" that dies with the message "xargs: echo: terminated by signal 13" when it gets SIGPIPE

Usefull links:
[link1](https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error)
[link2](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/sigpipe_handling.html)